# SimGrid. How to write comparator?

Tags: c, compare, simgrid

I have a dynamic array of hosts:

```
xbt_dynar_t dynar_host = xbt_dynar_new(sizeof(MSG_host_t), NULL);
```

Each host contains information about its speed in flops.
I want to sort it by their host's speed. In documentation I found function [xbt_dynar_sort](http://simgrid.gforge.inria.fr/simgrid/3.13/doc/group__XBT__dynar__array.html#ga666d4ca5510ffa9f2cc9a1463c19e935). This function accepts two parameters: dynamic array itself and comparator  `int_f_cpvoid_cpvoid_t compar_fn`.

Any advises or example how can this comparator be written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function only apply the standard `qsort` function to the data stored in the dynar, so you should also read the [libc documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Array-Sort-Function.html), the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) or [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) for more info.

So you should write a function somehow similar to the following:

```
int mycmp(void *a,void*b) 
{
  MSG_host_t hostA = *(MSG_host_t*)a;
  MSG_host_t hostB = *(MSG_host_t*)b;
  double valA = MSG_host_get_speed(hostA);
  double valB = MSG_host_get_speed(hostB)
  return (valA > valB) - (valA < valB);
}
```

And then, call `xbt_dynar_sort(dynar, mycmp)` to sort your dynar.

Note that the actual comparison on the return line of the function is a bit complicated. This is a way to obey the function semantic (return -1 if A < B, 0 if A==B and 1 if A > B) in a way that is numerically stable. This is as advised in the relevant [documentation of libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Comparison-Functions.html#Comparison-Functions).

Comment: Comparing values by subtraction is never a good idea. In this case the result might be inf, NaN, out of range, or a fraction value, all of them converted to an int yield either an invalid result or undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, @2501. I updated my code and added a little paragraph explaining the complex resulting syntax. Thanks for noticing!